# More fine grained sorting of methods using Eclipse Ganymede: Is there a good plugin available?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-plugin

These are the options we have out of the box:

[image]

I would like a more fine grained sorting when it comes to methods. I would like to:

1. Have all methods with a name which does not start with **get**, **is** or **set** first.
2. Then have the accessor methods (with names starting with get, is or set).

Individually the methods in `[1]` and `[2]` above could be sorted in alphabetical order. Apart from my devision of normal methods into two parts I like the existing sort order.

I find this order (with the accessor methods last) better as I'm more likely to find the non-accessor methods interesting when I'm maintaining a class and I need to fix a bug etc.

Is there a plugin I could use? If there is none, would it be hard to create this kind of plugin myself? (I have never created a Eclipse plugin.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it's not to late for my answer.

As far as I know, there is no such plugin (I looked at eclipse plugin central right now).

If you want to write such plugin, it shouldn't be too hard to write the refactoring (the Java Editor is based on an AST, that can be reached via extension points) itself, but for building a working plugin it might need more study.

Some resources that might help:

- Plugin development resources from stackoverflow: **question 592391** (sorry, but cannot post two hyperlinks)
- An open source refactoring plugin: http://code.google.com/p/tane/ (it currently contains a single refactoring plus the related gui elements, it might be a good example for you)

Answer (score 1):

In 2011, an academic [exercise resulted](http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/eclipse-clean-code-method-sorter-try-1.html) in an [Eclipse plugin implementing methods sorting based on ideas in Robert C. Martin's book "Clean Code"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Recommenders/CleanCodeMethodSorter). I am still trying to work out if I like it or not.

There is an open bug report to enhance sort member functionality in Eclise: [Sort Members doesn't provide a means to group getter/setter pairs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72418). It was opened in 2004 and still has no plans to be implemented.